# HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive not working properly

Tags: stm32, spi, stm32cubemx, hal, stm32f103

I am trying to use HAL function to drive SPI to read analog voltage from external ADC (adc128s102). I see what I expect to see in first 16 CLK with MISO(Blue) and MOSI(Yellow) line. But what's causing the next 16 CLK cycle after first transaction? I am sending 8 control bit to and read 12bit from ADC. First 16 CLK cycle seems to be more what I am expecting. Sorry for the low resolution image.. didn't have USB to export from the scope :(. Btw my ADC reference voltage is 5V and 12bit ADC. I am seeing 2V at the input of ADC and this is what I am trying to monitor on MISO.

**Scope Image**
[image: Scope]

**While loop**
[image]

**SPI Initialization Code**
[image]

**While loop Modification 1**
[image]

**SPI Initialization Modification 1**
[image]

**Modification 1 Results**

Time div 100ms/div
[image]

Time div 10us/div
[image]

**While loop Modification 2**
[image]

**SPI Initialization Modification 2**
[image]

**Modification 2 Results**
[image]

**While loop Modification 3**
[image]

**Modification 3 Results on Terminal**

32774
40710
29190
25094
37638
37126
32774
33798
41478
35590
45318
48134
40710
41222
47366
.....

Comment: In your `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive` call you asked for 2 transfers in the `Size` parameter and presumably you configured the peripheral for `SPI_DATASIZE_16BIT` when you initialized it  - so that's what you got: 2 transfers of 16 bits each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have configured your SPI peripheral to work with 16-bit instead of 8-bit data. Then you request transmitting 2 units of data which result to 2x16-bit => 32-bit transmission. Alternatively you can use 16-bit transfer, but then you need to do only one such transfer.

Additionally, you have wrong cast in HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive call. Since you arrays are of `uint8_t` type you do not need cast at all.

At last your buffers are wrong size. HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive transmits and receive data at the same time, if you transmit two bytes, both buffers must be of size 2.

TLDR:

1. Replace

   `hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_16BIT;`

   by

   `hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;`
2. Replace

   `uint8_t tx_data[1] = {0x08};`

   `uint8_t rx_data[1] = {0x00};`

   by

   `uint8_t tx_data[2] = {0x08, 0x00};`

   `uint8_t rx_data[2] = {0x00, 0x00};`
3. Replace

   `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi1, (uint8_t)tx_data, (uint8_t*)rx_data, 2, 10);`

   by

   `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi1, tx_data, rx_data, sizeof(rx_data), 10);`
4. Result you can reconstruct as

   `uint16_t adcval = (((uint16_t)rx_data[0]) << 8) | rx_data[1];`

Comment: Hi, how dose this code guarantee to read 12 bit if I only use 8 bit in one 16 CLK cycle? I am expecting to send 8bit data and read 12bit data in one 16CLK cycle. I am confused why it's necessary to have tx_data to have size of array 2 instead of 1 since I am sending only 8 bit.

Comment: I just tried your suggested code with 8 bit. I still see 2 x 16 cycles as described in the image in the post. I think I should still keep data parameter as 1 instead of sizeof(rx_data)

Comment: SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT constant is in pregenerated code from STM32CubeIDE. Check that after compiling STM32CubeIDE did not switched it back to 16-bit. If this happen, you need to update it in `.ioc` file (blue MX icon in Project Explorer) in Configuration panel which is visible after selecting SPI1 peripheral.

Comment: HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive do transmission and reception at the same time. If you transmit 16 clock pulses (2 bytes) you have 16-bits (2 bytes) transmitted on MOSI wire and in parellel there are at the same time 16-bit (2 byte) data on MISO, so you work with 4 bytes in total. `sizeof(rx_data)` is 2 in your case. It is better to use `sizeof` because it automaticaly changes if you decide extend/shring the buffer. I do not mask 12 of 16 bits in last command, but you do not need it because your ADC chip garantuee that upper 4 bits are zeroes.

Comment: Also note that your transaction should not be 4 + 12bits. See carefully Figure 1 in ADC datasheet. ADD0 bit is transmitted at the same time as DB11 bit. The value which you receive is value of previously selected channel, not channel selected this time. This is described in section 7.5.1 in ADC datasheet.

Comment: Hey, I've tried your suggested code above by using SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT. But the result is still two separate bytes and it seems wrong. In the modification 2, where I configured SPI_DATASIZE_16BIT and use data parameter as 1 in HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive, it seems closer to what I expected. Am I misunderstanding your suggestion? Please see modified post and the results.

Comment: and yes I am aware that the value I am reading is the preceding one. I am using only one channel at this time so I am not worried now.

Comment: In case of both modifications you still need to make tx_data 2 bytes long. If you do not trust me, then look at implementation: https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/stm32f4xx_hal_driver/blob/bfa4a8fde4fa5141619be006df8ef3e08265bd65/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_spi.c#L1193-L1197, for both Tx and Rx transfer length is the same Size parameter used and later, array of this size read/written. In case of using 16-bit mode it is convient make tx_data and rx_data uint16_t type, but in your case it is better to let it as uint8_t and for parsing value use the same formula for computing `uint16_t adcval`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no SPI initialization code so it may be wrong.

But you have TX and RX buffers with length of 1 byte. Yet your code tells to transmit and receive 2 bytes so it transmits out one garbage byte and will also overwrite SRAM after the RX buffer with one byte received from SPI.

In addition the code uses the tx buffer address incorrectly. It takes the address of tx_buffer, casts it to uint8_t, and passes it on as pointer to buffer. Which means the original 32-bit address is lost. So it will also send out data from wrong address.

Comment: Hi, I added SPI initialization code. Where are you getting 32-bit address..? I am still not understanding clearly as to why I am seeing 2nd 16 CLK cycles. Looking at the comment above, I can decrease SIZE parameter to 1. Is this all I have to do?

Comment: @K.Son Your init code tells to use 16-bit transaction and your main code tells to send two of 16 bit transactions, so 4 bytes transmitted and received.

Comment: Would it be possible to just send 1 byte and receive 2 byte?

Comment: I am trying to use this ADC (adc128s102) and get result as described in pg 8.

Comment: @K.Son It is possible but not with transmitreceive, you must transfer equal amount of bytes. You could use transmit and receive separately, but it might be less code on your end to transmitreceive 2 bytes.

Comment: I am having problem displaying those values on terminal using CDC_Transmit_FS.. do you have any suggestion? I updated the post with new code named Modification 3. I am using SPI_16bit data as you suggested and correct all buffer that im using